# odoo 11 changes to report renderer from odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-11

We've just upgraded from odoo 9 to **odoo 11**.  odoo 11 has had the Report printing functionality removed, meaning the old code I used of:

```py
report = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/report'.format('https://odoo.example.com'))
result = report.render_report(self.odooconnection1.db, self.odooconnection1.uid, self.odooconnection1.password, 'account.report_invoice', [invoice_id])
```

is now deprecated.

How do i go about programmatically downloading reports in odoo 11

Comment: I suggest reviewing the [Reports Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/reports.html#custom-reports) sections for "Custom Reports" and "Reports are web pages".

Comment: cheers for the comment @travisw but the code on there doesn't make a whole lot of sense, the context seems entirely missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this isn't the best way at all, and is a bit of a hack but i solved it by:

Using the python **requests** and **lxml** packages to make a request, manually login to the odoo site and then with that session, download the various PDF's i required.

```py
import requests
from lxml import html

def __download_report(self, invoice_ids, date_to_use):
        session_requests = requests.session()
        login_url = "https://odoo.example.com/web/login"
        result = session_requests.get(login_url)

        tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
        authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='csrf_token']/@value")))[0]
        payload = {
            "login": "username",
            "password": "password",
            "csrf_token": authenticity_token
        }
        result = session_requests.post(
            login_url,
            data = payload,
            headers = dict(referer=login_url)
        )
        for invoice_id in invoice_ids:
            filename = self.__get_file_name(invoice_id)

            url = "https://odoo.example.com/report/pdf/account.report_invoice/"+str(invoice_id)
            pdf = session_requests.get(
                url,
                stream=True
            )
            sys.stdout.write("\r[%s]" % filename )
            sys.stdout.flush()
            self.__save_report(pdf, filename, date_to_use)

def __save_report(self, report_data, filename, date_to_use):
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(report_data.content)
```